# Passing pointer to a temporary std::string to another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider the following C++ program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

std::string getString() {
    return "hello world";
}

void printString(const char* s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{       
    std::thread T(printString, getString().c_str());

    T.join();

    return 0;

}
```

The call to `getString()` will return a temporary `std::string` and the value `getString().c_str()` is a pointer to a temporary stack variable.

Since each thread has its own stack (but share the heap) then passing a pointer to a string on the main thread to some thread `T` shouldn't work in theory right?

Why does this code compile and run to print `hello world` ? Or am I running into some kind of undefined behavior?

EDIT:

What if the program looks like this (no threads)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

std::string getString() {
    return "hello world";
}

void printString(const char* s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{       
    printString(getString().c_str());                
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: *"some kind of undefined behavior"* Yes, the pointer is dangling.

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads having their own stack. Thread stack space is not private to the thread. `getString()`'s return object stops existing after the expression returns. There's no guarantee that the thread will finish it's work before then.

Comment: _The call to getString() will return a temporary std::string and the value getString().c_str() is a pointer to a temporary stack variable._

This is actually not true. Since C++11, `string::c_str()` does the same as `string::data()` and returns a pointer to the underlying array, so `getString().c_str()` is actually a pointer to a heap variable. But because `getString()` is temporary, this array is deleted before the pointer is used. That's why the pointer is dangling (as explained before).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or am I running into some kind of undefined behavior?

That is exactly what happens.  The string that was returned from `getString` only lives until the end of the epxresion

```
std::thread T(printString, getString().c_str());
```

That means that in `printString` you have a pointer to data that is no longer valid.  You might get what it contained, or something else can happen.  Accessing the pointer is undefined behavior so any result you get is "correct".

---

If you change `getString` to

```
const char * getString() {
    return "hello world";
}
```

and the  create the thread like

```
std::thread T(printString, getString());
```

Then this would be okay since `"hello world"` has static storage duration so it will live for the rest of the life of the program

Comment: Thank you. Does `"hello world"` have static storage because it's a literal? Does it live neither in the stack or the heap but rather in the "data" section of the binary? Does the `const`-ness impact anything? I also posted a minor edit to my original post regarding what happens with a normal function call, no threads.

Comment: @user11909399 Yes, it has static storage duration because it is a string literal.  All string literals have static storage duration.  The constness doesn't matter for that.  Regarding you edit, that code is legal since now the call to `pintString` is part of the full expression.